# Drupal 8 / How do i add an extra-class / highlight a 'view item' in a view list if the currentnode is the same?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I show a list of teasers within a view.
This view is included for this content type.
So it shows on every page of this contenttype.

How do i add a class to the view item so i ccan make it active?

Answer (score 0):

Depending of how are you render the view, you should use a preprocessor, example for a grid render

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view_grid(&$variables) {}
```

once you do that you can add some logic into the preprocessor and add the class according this logic

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view_grid(&$variables) {
  $options = $variables['view']->style_plugin->options;
  $item_num = 0;
  $items = [];

  // Iterate over each rendered views result row.
  foreach ($variables['rows'] as $item) {
    // Add item attributes

     $item_attrs = [];
     $item_attrs['class'] = "view-grid__item view-grid__item--{$item_num}";
     $items[$item_num]['attributes'] = new Attribute($item_attrs);

     // Add item.content
     $items[$item_num]['content'] = $item;

     // Increase, decrease or reset appropriate integers.
     $item_num++;

      }

     // Add items to the variables array.
    $variables['items'] = $items;
}
```

See more info here
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/8.2.x